# Display the related attributes of a MAX in an ACCESS query

Tags: sql, database, join, sum, max

I have 2 tables joined with political results and I need to have the votes SUM per county, and then the MAX of the vote counts per county, with the Party that relates to the MAX in another column. I'm having trouble getting the Party into the Query results without messing up the SUM and MAX columns.

This Table I can get with the Following SQL

```
County Name SumOfVoteCount  MaxOfVoteCount   OfficeID
Baker                 7253      4008                 S
```

```
SELECT NY_Race.[County Name], Sum(NY_Results.VoteCount) AS SumOfVoteCount, Max(NY_Results.VoteCount) AS MaxOfVoteCount
FROM NY_Race INNER JOIN NY_Results ON NY_Race.RaceCountyID = NY_Results.RaceCountyID
GROUP BY NY_Race.[County Name], NY_Race.OfficeID
HAVING (((NY_Race.OfficeID)="S"));
```

What I need is for the Party that has that 4008 vote total to be included in the query results, but when I try to select Party to be added, it shows all of them and messes up the SUM of the vote count, and I end of with this:

```
County Name       SumOfVoteCount MaxOfVoteCount1    Party   OfficeID
Baker                       2927    2927              Dem       S
Baker                       4008    4008              GOP       S
Baker                        101    101               Lib       S
Baker                         53     53               Prg       S 
Baker                        164    164                WF       S
```

This is the SQL code I am using that gets the above Table:

```
SELECT NY_Race.[County Name], Sum(NY_Results.VoteCount) AS SumOfVoteCount, Max(NY_Results.VoteCount) AS MaxOfVoteCount, NY_Results.Party
FROM NY_Race INNER JOIN NY_Results ON NY_Race.RaceCountyID = NY_Results.RaceCountyID
GROUP BY NY_Race.[County Name], NY_Race.OfficeID, NY_Results.Party
HAVING (((OR_Race.OfficeID)="S"));
```

How can I get this table in the query results?

```
County Name     SumOfVoteCount  MaxOfVoteCount     Party  OfficeID
Baker                 7253        4008               GOP     S
```

I can't help but think I'm missing a WHERE claus somewhere that compares Party to MAXofVoteCount

Comment: I edited the question to make it a little easier to read. I could see that the Oregon prefix "OR" was confusing so I changed it to NY. The query also didn't involve one of the tables so I took that table join out of the query.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach these is to have a nested subquery that gets the MAX() for the field of interest. Then, only select the record with that MAX(). Here's the structure:

```
select COUNTY_NAME, R1.*
, (select sum(votecount) from results R2 where R1.COUNTY_ID=R2.COUNTY_ID and R1.OFFICE_ID=R2.OFFICE_ID)
 from RESULTS R1 
 join RACE on R1.COUNTY_ID=RACE.COUNTY_ID and R1.OFFICE_ID=RACE.OFFICE_ID
where R1.office_id = 'S' 
and voteCount =
(select max(votecount) from results R3 where R1.COUNTY_ID=R3.COUNTY_ID and R1.OFFICE_ID=R3.OFFICE_ID)
```

I created [a demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59157/27).

One issue: what if two get exactly the same number of votes. That's a functional issue you will have to resolve.

Comment: Thanks for your look at the problem. I can see how the results work with the one table, but I don't see a Join happening with your RACE table. In other words, how would I get the County_Name, that is an attribute in your RACE table, to show up in the query results?

Comment: Just join RACE. I kept the query simple to illustrate the concept. I have edited it now to add back the join: check the answer above.

Comment: OK, you got me started with the SQL that works for showing the Attributes that relate to the MAX record of vote count per county. But, it's giving me trouble including a field that has the SUM of Vote Counts by County. In your example there would need to be a field for SumofVoteCount, that would show Baker County has 3,160 total votes, and Ottawa had 6,000 total votes.

Comment: What DBMS are you using. If your SQL dialect allows a nested SELECT as a column in the outer select clause, you can use that. Will edit the answer to add that.

Comment: I'm using MS ACCESS 2010

Comment: I'm getting the Table I need with this SQL and your Demo:          select RACE.COUNTY_NAME, sum(VoteCount),
(select max(votecount) from results R2 where R1.COUNTY_ID=R2.COUNTY_ID and R1.OFFICE_ID=R2.OFFICE_ID) AS MaxVoteCount,
R1.Party
from RESULTS R1 join RACE on R1.COUNTY_ID=RACE.COUNTY_ID and R1.OFFICE_ID=RACE.OFFICE_ID
where  R1.OFFICE_ID = 'S'
group by COUNTY_NAME; But, this does not work in ACCESS, it's saying Party is not a part of an aggregate function. But, when I get rid of that by GROUP BY Party, it throws off my results. Is MySQL the only solution I have, is ACCESS possible?

Comment: MS-Access may work fine. I'm just not sure what syntax it supports. I have edited the SQL in the query again. if that does not work in MS-Access, does this query work (just in terms of syntax):  
select COUNTY_NAME, R1.*
, (select sum(votecount) from results R2 where R1.COUNTY_ID=R2.COUNTY_ID and R1.OFFICE_ID=R2.OFFICE_ID)
 from RESULTS R1 
 join RACE on R1.COUNTY_ID=RACE.COUNTY_ID and R1.OFFICE_ID=RACE.OFFICE_ID
where R1.office_id = 'S' 
and voteCount =
(select max(votecount) from results R3 where R1.COUNTY_ID=R3.COUNTY_ID and R1.OFFICE_ID=R3.OFFICE_ID)